# Sortable working with 1.7.2 but not with 1.11.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I use **sortable** function to be able to sort some textareas (I want to be able to sort textarea and to color text inside those textarea.)

It is working fine when using 1.7.2 version of jQuery, but it is not working anymore when using jQuery 1.11.2

here my [code in js.do](http://js.do/Aleqxs/drag-drop-textarea) (the code is with 1.7.2, but if you change 7 for 11 the sortable functionality wont be working anymore)

Here line 29,30,31 of my code

```
    //LINES_ISSUE_START
    $('.sortable').sortable({
        cancel: '.textarea,.block_bouton_color'
    });   
    //LINES_ISSUE_END
```

Any idea about how to fix it?

Comment: Your selector string has a stray comma at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change this

```
cancel: '.textarea,.block_bouton_color,',
```

to this

```
 cancel: '.textarea,.block_bouton_color'
```

and include the jQuery migrate plugin.

Comment: why use jquery migrate plugin? is there no possible way to have sortable that works with sortable function under 1.11.2 version of Jquery?

Comment: You can also upgrade your version of jquery-ui, that works too

Comment: I tried it... haven't find any combination working. which version of jquery-ui version should I use?

Comment: Preferably the latest one, I will try to take another look soon

Answer (score -1):

OK now it is working

here the changement I made

1/ I use jquery_1.11.2 as I wanted (standard to user bootstrap)
2/ I switch for jquery_UI_1.11.4 (last version at the time I am writing) 
3/ As recommanded by meskobalazs I modify the line cancel as follow without ","

```
cancel: '.textarea,.block_bouton_color'
```

4/ Finally I had to add

```
$(".sortable").sortable();
```

HERE THE CODE (BEFORE ANY MODIFICATION)

```
$(".sortable").delegate(".bouton_ordre_drag_and_drop","mouseover",function(){
    $(".sortable").sortable("enable");   
    $(".sortable").sortable({   
        cancel: '.textarea,.block_bouton_color,',
    });   
});
```

HERE THE CODE (AFTER MODIFICATION)

```
$(".sortable").sortable();
$(".sortable").delegate(".bouton_ordre_drag_and_drop","mouseover",function(){
    $(".sortable").sortable("enable");   
    $(".sortable").sortable({   
        cancel: '.textarea,.block_bouton_color'
    });   
});
```